# Editing static content

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm generally really impressed with Bolt and the flexibility it provides me for creating contenttypes with specific fields with minutes.  However, I have a template which has common content across the site that I would like to make editable without allowing the user to edit the .twig files directly.

I've considered creating a different contenttype just for each part of the template but this seems inefficient.

For example I would like to make the address editable, and a panel that contains text and three images.  Just wondering if there's a sensible way for achieving this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create [resource ContentTypes](https://docs.bolt.cm/howto/resource-contenttype) for this type of stuff, then you can put that into inheritable Twig files that you can then [{% include '' %}](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) as required.

Comment: Excellent,  the process of make it non rout able and the granular permissions make this perfect.